# how to make touch slider responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to change my gallery into touch slider for mobile devices only. For achieving my goal , i create two sections, i for desktop and another for mobile.i am using display property on media query. but my slider is not responsive.i applied width:100%, but it's still not working as well. i want to make it responsive and i want to add next or previous on slider as well.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
if (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints) {

  $('#slider').addClass('ms-touch');

  $('#slider').on('scroll', function() {
    $('.slide-image').css('transform','translate3d(-' + (100-$(this).scrollLeft()/6) + 'px,0,0)');
  });

} else {

  var slider = {

    el: {
      slider: $("#slider"),
      holder: $(".holder"),
      imgSlide: $(".slide-image")
    },

    slideWidth: $('#slider').width(),
    touchstartx: undefined,
    touchmovex: undefined,
    movex: undefined,
    index: 0,
    longTouch: undefined,
    
    init: function() {
      this.bindUIEvents();
    },

    bindUIEvents: function() {

      this.el.holder.on("touchstart", function(event) {
        slider.start(event);
      });

      this.el.holder.on("touchmove", function(event) {
        slider.move(event);
      });

      this.el.holder.on("touchend", function(event) {
        slider.end(event);
      });

    },

    start: function(event) {
      // Test for flick.
      this.longTouch = false;
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.slider.longTouch = true;
      }, 250);

      // Get the original touch position.
      this.touchstartx =  event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

      // The movement gets all janky if there's a transition on the elements.
      $('.animate').removeClass('animate');
    },

    move: function(event) {
      // Continuously return touch position.
      this.touchmovex =  event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
      // Calculate distance to translate holder.
      this.movex = this.index*this.slideWidth + (this.touchstartx - this.touchmovex);
      // Defines the speed the images should move at.
      var panx = 100-this.movex/6;
      if (this.movex < 600) { // Makes the holder stop moving when there is no more content.
        this.el.holder.css('transform','translate3d(-' + this.movex + 'px,0,0)');
      }
      if (panx < 100) { // Corrects an edge-case problem where the background image moves without the container moving.
        this.el.imgSlide.css('transform','translate3d(-' + panx + 'px,0,0)');
      }
    },

    end: function(event) {
      // Calculate the distance swiped.
      var absMove = Math.abs(this.index*this.slideWidth - this.movex);
      // Calculate the index. All other calculations are based on the index.
      if (absMove > this.slideWidth/2 || this.longTouch === false) {
        if (this.movex > this.index*this.slideWidth && this.index < 2) {
          this.index++;
        } else if (this.movex < this.index*this.slideWidth && this.index > 0) {
          this.index--;
        }
      }      
      // Move and animate the elements.
      this.el.holder.addClass('animate').css('transform', 'translate3d(-' + this.index*this.slideWidth + 'px,0,0)');
      this.el.imgSlide.addClass('animate').css('transform', 'translate3d(-' + 100-this.index*50 + 'px,0,0)');

    }

  };

  slider.init();
}
});
```

```css
div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
 background-color:white;
}


/* touch screen carousel */

.slider-wrap {
display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
section{
display:none;
}
.animate {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

.slider-wrap {
  display:block;
}

.slider {
 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ms-touch.slider {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* Hides the scrollbar. */
  
  -ms-scroll-chaining: none;
  /* Prevents Metro from swiping to the next tab or app. */
  
  -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  /* Forces a snap scroll behavior on your images. */
  
  -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: snapInterval(0%, 100%);
  /* Defines the y and x intervals to snap to when scrolling. */
}

.holder {
  width: 300%;
  max-height: 500px;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.slide-wrapper {

  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.temp {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}

.slide img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translatex(-100px);
}

.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide div {
  z-index: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="slider" id="slider">
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="slide-wrapper">
        <div class="slide"><img class="slide-image" src="images/homepage-banner-15.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
        <span class="desc"><a href="/signing-board/">Signing Boards</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-wrapper">
        <div class="slide"><img class="slide-image" src="images/homepage-banner-12.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
        <span class="desc"><a href="/floating-picture-frames/">Fine Art Frame</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-wrapper">
        <div class="slide"><img class="slide-image" src="images/homepage-banner-14.jpg" width="100%"/></div>
        <span class="desc">><a href="/paper-samples/">Paper Samples</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
 <div class="previous"></div>
    <div class="next"></div>    
 
  </div>
</div> 
   <section class="py-5 mb-3"> 
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row sectorGap justify-content-center">
    <div class="col gallery">
            <a href="/signing-board/"><img src="images/homepage-banner-15.jpg" width="100%" class="myImage"/></a>
   <div class="desc"><h2><a href="/signing-board/">Signing Boards</a></h2></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col gallery">
      <a href="/floating-picture-frames/"><img src="images/homepage-banner-12.jpg" width="100%" class="myImage"/></a>
            <div class="desc"><h2><a href="/floating-picture-frames/">Fine Art Frame</a></h2></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col gallery">
      <a href="/paper-samples/"><img src="images/homepage-banner-14.jpg" width="100%" class="myImage"/></a>
            <div class="desc"><h2><a href="/paper-samples/">Paper Samples</a></h2></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
   </div>
    </section>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Can you use plugins like Owl Carousel? https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Comment: thanks david for your suggestions. but i want to fix my above code. could you please tell me is it possible to convert gallery into carousel for mobile only using owl carousel. i don't want to write two segments.  thanks

Comment: Based on what you want to achieve, it's better to just have gallery in 2 sections, and show/hide 1 of them according to your breakpoint requirements.

Comment: remove this css `transform: translatex(-100px);`

Comment: if i'll remove transform , touch slider will not work properly.. :-(

Comment: @DavidLiang , thanks, i am using two section for achieving my goal. but problem is for mobile my slider is not taking 100% width..

Comment: if you not remove above the css it will not take 100%

Comment: if i remove the above css. i'll not able to slide to next photos.. it should stop in 2. than again i'll slide , it'll stop on 3.

Comment: your slider not working for me in below with 768px in web

Comment: my slider is for mobile only... and its working, but not covering 100% for a image. it's is showing image with some white space, or two image stick together... for desktop, i don't have carousel, just a row with 3 coloumn.

Comment: check the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gVFN.png

Comment: drag it, you'll able to see next. it is not auto

Comment: i cannot drag it.

Comment: but i can . use mozilla or upload it somewhere so that you can access through mobile

Comment: try this https://codepen.io/foleyatwork/pen/ylwoz

Comment: it not working.. :(

Comment: open in your mobile.. you can test..or save this file on ftp.. than test..

Answer (score 0):

As what I said in the comment, you can achieve what you want by duplicating all the images into another section, show/hide one of them based on the break point, and apply the carousel library (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) on mobile.

Use the carousel library instead of build one yourself saves you time and effort, as Touch and Drag support is not easy to do.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Display as block until md breakpoint (768px) -->
    <section class="owl-carousel owl-theme d-md-none">
        <div class="item">
            <img class="img-fluid" alt="image 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="img-fluid" alt="image 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="img-fluid" alt="image 3" />
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Display none until md breakpoint (768px), as block after -->
    <section class="gallery d-none d-md-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img class="img-fluid" alt="image 1" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img class="img-fluid" alt="image 2" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img class="img-fluid" alt="image 3" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

This markup enables you to only show carousel section when the screen < 768px, and only show gallery section otherwise.

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        items: 1
    });
});
```

This will turn the carousel section into touch-and-drag-enabled carousel. You can read its documentation here: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-welcome.html

#### Result

On small screen:
[image]

On larger screen:
[image]

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/243804/

Comment: thanks david  for your response.. i don't want to use owl carousel. my carousel is now working fine but text is override on image.here is the details :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668564/text-or-image-overide-on-slider-z-index-oveflow-inline-block-nothing-find